# Send otp via email from my Android app for signup & verification

Tags: android, email, smtp, one-time-password

I have tried to use the email sending method for sending a random number as otp to the email addresses- BUT this only works on the devices that installed app dirctly from android studio BUT the devices which installed the generated apk cannot send the emails
I used the normal email sending code for sending the otp..(But the email sending only works on the device that installed the app directly from android studio..

```
Random rand = new Random();
        n = rand.nextInt(55320) + 1;

        rec = reciep.getText().toString();
        ml = rec;
        subject = "Your OTP FOR app";
        textMessage = "YOUR OTP IS ->" + n;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("myemail", "mypassword");
            }
        });

        pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Sending OTP...", true);

        RetreiveFeedTask task = new RetreiveFeedTask();
        task.execute();

    }
}
```

Comment: can you please help me out with  the answer? @Noise Generator

Comment: I don't know the answer. I don't use this method to send emails. I use an intent which opens the default mailer.

Answer (score 2):

Go on google and turn on less secure app
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps